# Sticky Footer Issue When Page Scrolls

Tags: css, responsive-design, sticky-footer

I have applied a sticky footer according to this page:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

It works fine, but my design is responsive and the page height grows larger than a screen height, but the footer remains sticky.  In other words, no matter how much content I have, the footer still starts (in this example) 142 px from the bottom.

What I want is the sticky footer if the page height is less than screen height, but if the page height is larger, I simply want the page to scroll to the footer.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width:1220px;
    margin:0 auto -124px auto;
}

.footer, .content:after {
    height: 124px; 
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}    

<div class="content">content here....</div>
<div class="footer">footer here...</div>
```

Comment: There are answers to this all over stackoverflow... But for the most part they all point to here: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Follow the guide there and you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

P.S. there's a link that says "learn about using it" in case you were looking for it on the site

Comment: Your code works fine in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/edw1es8j/